# What should buffer size be when reading/writing to smb share?

Tags: networking, posix, smb

Say I open a file descriptor on a file located in a mounted smb share and I intend to write bytes to it.  Given the environment is macos and the posix functions `size_t write(int fildes, const void *buf, size_t nbyte)` & `size_t read(int fildes, void *buf, size_t nbyte)`, how can I figure out the optimal value for `nbyte`?